# Web API will not accept XML

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a web service with Web API which will accept an XML file incoming from an SAP PI system. I have the XML format but the web service will not accept it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:ContactUs xmlns:ns0="http://customdomain.com/ContactUs">
 <userId></userId>
 <firstName></firstName>
 <lastName></lastName>
 <e_mail></e_mail>
 <gsm></gsm>
 <country></country>
 <city></city>
 <subject></subject>
 <type></type>
 <detail></detail>
 <message></message>
 <orderId></orderId>
 <storeName></storeName>
</ns0:ContactUs>
```

I tried decorating the controller with DataContract and looks like it accepts the namespace now but I'm getting the request is invalid error saying all the fields are required (in JSON BTW) although they all are being sent.

I'm using Postman when testing with raw XML file and accept/xml header.

Here is the controller POST method and the model:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomerRecord(CustomerRecord customerrecord)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && customerrecord != null)
        {
            db.CustomerRecords.Add(customerrecord);
            db.SaveChanges();
            try
            {
                Mailing.SendMail.Send();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, customerrecord);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = customerrecord.Id }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }

namespace ContactUs.Models
{
[DataContract(Namespace="http://customdomain.com/ContactUs", Name="ContactUs")]
public class CustomerRecord
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name="type")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string gsm { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string e_mail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string detail { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [DataMember]
    public string storeName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [DataMember]
    public string userID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [DataMember]
    public string orderID { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: Try matching the name of your model's property with the XML field name i.e. model's orderID and XML's orderId. See if that changes anything.

Comment: It is already that way. I changed the XML so it will match letter cases but does not work.